# Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac issue

Tags: powershell, nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy, dacpac

I'm trying to deploy an MVC Project along with a database using Octopus. When the step for deploying the database is hit I'm getting the following error:

```
  Types            : {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage, 
               Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.NestedDeploymentPropertyAttribute, 
               Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacExportOptions, 
               Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacImportOptions...}
  LoaderExceptions : {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
               assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, 
               Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its 
               dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
               File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, 
               Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
               WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
               To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry 
               value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 
               1.
               Note: There is some performance penalty associated with 
               assembly bind failure logging.
               To turn this feature off, remove the registry value 
               [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
               , System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
               assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, 
               Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its 
               dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
               File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, 
               Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
               WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
               To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry 
               value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 
               1.
               Note: There is some performance penalty associated with 
               assembly bind failure logging.
               To turn this feature off, remove the registry value 
               [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
               }
 Message          : Unable to load one or more of the requested types Retrieve 
               the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
 Data             : {}
 InnerException   : 
 TargetSite       : System.RuntimeType[] 
               GetTypes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule)
 StackTrace       :    at 
               System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule 
               module)
                  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
                  at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand.LoadAssemblyFromPathOrName(List`1 generatedTypes)
                  at 
               Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand.EndProcessing()
                  at 
               System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
 HelpLink         : 
 Source           : mscorlib
 HResult          : -2146232830
```

The Deploy.ps1 file looks like this:

```
 try{

    # Add the DLL
    # For 64-bit machines
    Write-Host "Add Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
    Add-Type -path ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll")
    Write-Host "Add Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"
    Add-Type -path ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll")

    # Create the connection string
    $services = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices ("Data Source=$dbSource;User Id=$dbAdminUser;Password=$dbAdminPassword")

    Write-Host "Load the dacpac " + ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\Resources\Database.publish.xml")
    #Load the dacpac
    $dacpac = ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\Resources\Database.dacpac")
    $dacpacoptions = ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\Resources\Database.publish.xml")

    Write-Host "Add variables"

    #Add the variables to the options

    Write-Host $dacpac
    Write-Host $dacpacoptions


    Write-Host "setting dp"
    #Load dacpac from file & deploy to database
    $dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($dacpac)


    Write-Host "dacProfile set"
    #Read a publish profile XML to get the deployment options
    $dacProfile = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacProfile]::Load($dacpacoptions)


    Write-Host "Add dbName"
    $dacProfile.DeployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues["dbName"] = $dbName
    Write-Host "Add dbUser"
    $dacProfile.DeployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues["dbUsername"] =  $dbUser
    Write-Host "Add dbPassword"
    $dacProfile.DeployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues["dbPassword"] = $dbPassword

    Write-Host "About to deploy the dacpac"
    # Deploy the dacpac
    $services.Deploy($dp, $dbName, $TRUE, $dacProfile.DeployOptions)

    # Configure IIS
    .\DeployScripts\IISConfiguration.ps1
}
catch [Exception]
{ 
    $_.Exception|format-list -force
    Exit -1
}
```

I'm using the NuGet package for Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac v 1.0.1, and the NuGet Package for Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom v 13.0.1601.5. Both of those NuGet packages are currently the latest for those dlls to the best of my knowledge. The dacpac is geared towards SQL Server 2014. I'm not sure what other information would be useful here. The server I'm deploying to doesn't have SqlPackage.exe so I can't use that. Any and all help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From the logs it looks like its unable to find the assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom" at the location being search for

Comment: Yeah, it says it's looking for version 12.0.0, however I have version 13.0.1

Comment: Add-Type -path ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll").. Is this looking at the correct directory.. May be you could try and load this by giving an explicit path - e.g C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies